# Proof of the theorem "Any recursive relation is representable in Cn A$_E$."

Tags: logic, incompleteness

I'm reading Godel incompleteness theorem from Mathematical introduction to logic by Enderton. There is something about recursive functions I don't get.
In the text it first says:

"DEFINITION. A relation R on the natural numbers is recursive iff it
is representable in some consistent finitely axiomatizable theory"

Theorem: Any recursive relation is representable in Cn A$_E$.

PROOF. Recall that the relation R is recursive iff there is some finite
consistent set A of sentences such that some formula ρ represents
R in CnA. (There is no loss of generality in assuming that the
language has only finitely many parameters: those in the finite set
A, those in ρ, and 0, S, and ∀.) In the case of a unary relation R,
we have that a ∈ R iff the least D which is a deduction from A of
either ρ(S$^a$0) or ¬ ρ(S$^a$0) is, in fact, a deduction of the former.
More formally, a ∈ R iff the last component of f(a) is ρ(S$^a$0),where

f (a) = the least d such that d is in the set of item 18 and the
last component of d is either ρ(S$^a$0) or¬ ρ(S$^a$0).
For this (fixed) ρ, there always is such a d.

Can you explain why defining f as it is proves the representability of R?

Comment: What part of the proof don't you get?

Comment: what's the point of defining f(a) as a function? if we want to show that R is a relation in Cn A$_E$ we need to say there is a formula which represents R in Cn‌  A$_E$. so what is this formula in this case? can you explain it. @NoahSchweber

Comment: @Sarah The formula $\varphi(a)$ is "the last component of $f(a)$ is $\#\rho(S^a0)$," so the definition of $f$ is part of the definition of the formula. (Also, in your transcription you are missing something to indicate that we are talking about the Godel number of the formula $\rho(S^a)$, not the formula itself...)